# Unable to install nuget packages, they are all unable to be found

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, elmah

After running `Install-Package Elmah.MVC`, I get the following error in Visual Studio:

```
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Elmah.MVC'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Elmah.MVC
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

For my Package Source, I've tried both the following, to no avail. I've even tried `Install-Package EntityFramework`, and same error.

`https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/`
`https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solutions to cope with your issue:

**Solution # 1**

1. Delete all the folders inside of the packages folder.
2. Update all packages in Nuget Package Manager.

**Solution # 2**

type in the package manager console `Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -force`, then delete the EntityFramework Folder in Package Folder, and then install it again `Install-Package EntityFramework`

**Solution #3**

Use the following link : https://docs.nuget.org/Release-Notes/Known-Issues

From the VS command prompt, run the following command:

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\VsLangproj.olb"
```

**Solution #4**

Clear the package Cache:

Tools->package Manager->Package Manager Settings-> Clear Package Cache

I hope one of the above methods will help you solve the issue.

Comment: Do you know the command does? - I'm having issues with NuGet in Visual Studio 2012 and I tried all solutions except the command one, I want to be sure before proceeed.

Comment: regsvr32 (Register Server) is a command-line utility in Microsoft Windows and ReactOS[1] for registering and unregistering DLLs 

Meaning it will register VsLangproj.olb

Comment: more on that regsvr32 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regsvr32